# Accessing Backbone js model in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

is it possible to access Backbone.js model's attribute or function in javascript? 
If possible how to do that??

My model :

> ```
> var TimeZone = Backbone.Model.extend({
>     defaults:{
>         timeZoneID : 'EST5EDT',
>         timeZoneShortForm : "ET",
>         timeZoneLongForm : "Eastern Time",
>      }
>    });
> ```

Javascript

> ```
>  getTimeZoneId :function(TimeZone)          
>     {
>            //here for given TimeZone model.. i have to acess the timeZoneID
>     }
> ```

Now i have to access timeZoneID.. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you are trying to access an instance of `TimeZone`:

```
var timeZone = new TimeZone();
timeZone.get('timeZoneID');
```

http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-get

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply.. yes, the mistake is i was not passing the instance.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Stupid karma is a good reward for people who work to help you, I recommend you "upvote" and/or "accept" the answers those have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Backbone.js is a JavaScript framework, so your Backbone model is JavaScript, just like your `getTimeZoneId` function.

`Backbone.Model.extend()` creates a model constructor function, with which you’re expected to create instances (e.g. `var mymodel = new TimeZone();`).

It’s not quite clear from your question whether you want to get the `timeZoneID` of a model instance, or the `timeZoneID` property from the `defaults` object of your `TimeZone` prototype model object.

If you’ve got an `TimeZone` instance called `mymodel`, you can get its timeZoneID like this:

```
 mymodel.get('timeZoneID');
```

However, you can’t (I don’t think) inspect the `defaults` object of `TimeZone`. `Backbone.Model.extend()` returns a function which doesn’t expose any of the properties of the object you pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

Like ponzano said, it seems you want the following:

```
getTimeZoneId :function(timeZone){
  return timeZone.get('timeZoneID');
}
```

Note however, that the `timeZone` function argument is lower case. Don't use the upper case, or you will mix it up with the model "class".

Of course, sine Backbone already define getters and setters, you might not need your extra function at all...

In addition, maybe you shouldn't have the `var` in front of the model definition so that it is part of the global namespace and accessible form everywhere within your application.